# Polling and pagination at the same time with GraphQL Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

- To implement pagination with Apollo, you're typically going to use the `fetchMore` function, given to you when you send a query, in combination with `updateQuery` to tell Apollo how to update its cache with the result (appending it onto what you already have).
- To implement near real-time syncs, you're typically going to use polling, which will resend your initial query every x seconds.

So polling refetches your initial query and will overwrite the cache, so you lose pagination and all the `fetchMore` stuff you added to the cache via `updateQuery`.

My question : How can one do polling **and** pagination at the same time while keeping a great user experience ? *(without subscriptions)*

Answer (score 1):

You can't. They were not intended to be used together.

Sources:

- https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1121
- https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1087

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented polling manually. It starts polling in `onCompleted` and resets it in `handleFetchMore`.

If a refetch-query is issued with changed options / variables, it looks like a new query for Apollo Client and hence the data is set to undefined during loading of the refetch-query. To avoid empty data on polling-refetch, a buffered data state is used.

```js
export const MyComponent = () => {
  // if a refetch-query is issued with changed options / variables, it looks like a new query for Apollo Client and hence the data is set to undefined during loading. To avoid empty data on polling-refetch, a buffered data state is used
  const [bufferedData, setBufferedData] = useState<
    YourDataType | undefined
  >();

  const intervalId = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | undefined>();
  const resetPolling = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
    intervalId.current = undefined;
  };

  const POLL_INTERVAL = 5000;
  const { fetchMore, refetch, variables, networkStatus } =
    useQuery({
      variables: {
        options: {
          filter,
          limit: itemsPerPage,
          offset: 0,
        },
      },
      onCompleted: (data: YourDataType) => {
        if (data) {
          setBufferedData(data);

          // start polling
          const newLastOffset = data?.items.length ?? 0;
          if (!intervalId.current) {
            intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
              refetch({
                ...variables,
                options: {
                  ...variables?.options,
                  offset: 0,
                  limit: newLastOffset,
                },
              });
            }, POLL_INTERVAL);
          }
        }
      },
      onError: () => setBufferedData(undefined),
    });

  const fetchingMore = networkStatus === NetworkStatus.fetchMore;

  const handleFetchMore = useCallback(() => {
    if (!fetchingMore) {
      resetPolling();
      fetchMore({
        variables: {
          options: {
            filter,
            limit: itemsPerPage,
            offset: bufferedData?.items.length ?? 0,
          },
        },
        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
          if (!fetchMoreResult || !fetchMoreResult) return prev;

          const merged = [...(prev?.items ?? [])];

          (fetchMoreResult.items ?? []).forEach((item) => {
            if (
              item &&
              !merged.find(
                (mergedItem) => mergedItem && mergedItem.id === item.id
              )
            ) {
              merged.push(item);
            }
          });

          return merged;
        },
      });
    }
  }, [bufferedData?.items.length, fetchMore, fetchingMore]);
};
```